# Add class based on text options clicked

Tags: html, selection, chain

I am in the middle of building my portfolio. What I would like to do:

I would like to let my user 'ask questions' by clicking a chain of divs, depending on each div clicked, possible options connected to that div will then highlight and when the question has been asked, a answer depending on the specific chain would then appear (what type of answer is not important).

So if I have 5 divs:

```
<div class="what">What</div>
<div class="would">Would</div>
<div class="like">Like</div>
<div class="you">You</div>
<div class="i">I</div>
```

And my user clicks on the **'What'** div, the **'Would'** div would highlight (add a class), if then clicked, the **'You'** and **'I'** divs would highlight and so forth. This would enable my user to ask a question based on the original word/div clicked and which words I then have chosen to 'connect' to that word/div.

I would then like to be able to use the specific string (of words) to fun a function, append a class or such. So that the question **'What'**, **'Would'**, **'You'** and **'Like'** would, as an example show a choice of 3 sentences to choose from, but the question of **'What'**, **'Would'**, **'I'** and **'Like'** would, as an example show a picture of a hotdog or some sort.

I do know a bit of JavaScript, but a little more jQuery, so I would prefer to work in that language if possible. I know that the question is a little complex and that I have not included any code, but I really did not know how to go around this.

Comment: I read the question twice, and still don't quite get the idea. Could you please summarize? So you have a couple of options (the div tags) to choose from, and each time you click on one - it gets highlighted (multiple selection allowed). Then, based on which particular words have been highlighted, you would like to show something - answer, picture or whatever. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am sorry that the question is so confusing, it was hard for me to get into words. 

You are both right and wrong, It is not the div tag clicked that gets highlighted but the next possible options that does. So if 'what' div is clicked, 'if', 'could', 'are' and so forth would be highlighted and clickable, but words that have no connection to 'what', like 'pancakes' 'Martin' or such, these are just examples, do not get highlighted and are not clickable.

And to your 2'nd part, yes, that's exactly what I am trying to achieve.
Thank you very much for your comment and I hope this helped explain.

Comment: I think it is better to use a json to build a tree. So it will be maintainable.

Comment: There's only a certain number of words that needs to be used. Nothing more than 20 to be precise, the combinations would probably end up around 25 or so. If possible I would like it the code to be fairly simple as this is, sadly, by far, my forte.

Comment: If not a `JSON`, what about nesting the *depending* div tags inside the one that needs to be clicked in order to make them highlighted?

Comment: I do not think this would be possible as some depending div tags can be highlighted from more than one word / div tag. Like the word 'are' would be highlighted by both 'what' as in 'What are your skills?', but also by 'when' as in 'When are you available?'. Otherwise I would certainly agree that that would be the easiest way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question. Maybe like this?

```
  <style type="text/css">
        .highlighted{
    background-color:yellow;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".test").click(function(){
            var id = this.id ;
            id++;
            if(id>5){
                id =1;
            }
            $( ".test" ).removeClass( "highlighted" );
           $( "#"+id ).addClass( "highlighted" );
        });
    });

    </script>

    <div class="what test" id="1">What</div>
    <div class="would test" id="2">Would</div>
    <div class="like test" id="3">Like</div>
    <div class="you test" id="4">You</div>
    <div class="i test" id="5">I</div>
```

Comment: Again, I am sorry that my question is very confusing, but thank you for your suggestion.

This is however not what I am looking for. I would like to be able to control exactly which divs get highlighted in this part of the code. so that, as an example 'would test' would highlight 'you test' and 'I test' if clicked. So that I can control which divs my user clicks after the initial word and so control what 'sentences' or chains of divs are clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help:

```
  <style type="text/css">
        .highlighted{
    background-color:yellow;
    }
    .container2 , .container1{
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $(".Common").click(function(){ 
            var classes = $(this).attr("data"); 

            $( ".highlighted" ).removeClass( "highlighted" );
           $( "."+classes ).addClass( "highlighted" );
        });
    });

    </script>
    <div class="container1">
    <div data="FRUITS" class="Common">FRUITS</div>
    <div data="VEGETABLES" class="Common">VEGETABLES</div>
    <div data="ANIMALS" class="Common">ANIMALS</div>
    <div data="BIRDS" class="Common">BIRDS</div>
    </div>

    <div class="container2" >
        <div class="BIRDS" >Parrot</div>
        <div class="FRUITS" >Apples</div>
        <div class="VEGETABLES" >Cucumber</div>
        <div class="FRUITS" >Oranges</div>
         <div class="VEGETABLES" >Carrot</div>
        <div class="ANIMALS" >Lion</div>
        <div class="BIRDS" >Dove</div>
        <div class="ANIMALS" >Tiger</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes, that is absolutely wonderful, I could really use that, thank you!

I have now changed your version slightly to do what I want it to do:
https://jsfiddle.net/au8o0Lz6/
As you can see, I have added .chosen to show the user which options / divs they have clicked.

I now would like to be able to run a unique function depending on the words chosen - A different function for a different list of words chosen / for each different question. Might you have a suggestion how to do that?

Again thank you for your time and help.